# To select all from a table using one distinct value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, windows, sql-server-2008

First of all I am newbie to SQL Server 2008.

I looking for a query where we need to eliminate duplicate records from two different tables.

Where as the data on both the tables are same.

I tried to use

```
select Col1, col2, col3 from table1
union
select Col1, col2, col3 from table2
```

where I got the answer but there is a col (Sl no) which is unique and all the records are coming along with it. Same issue while using distinct keyword too.

The column names are:

```
SL NO datatype = int    
Name datatype= varchar (255)
Payment Mode datatype=Varchar (255)
Amount = int
```

Please help me with the code.

Comment: How do you define duplicate records?

Comment: Then just don't include SL NO column in your selects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [SL NO] in both tables actually has the same col2, col3 try

```
SELECT * from table1
WHERE [SL NO] not in (SELECT [SL NO] from TABLE2)
UNION
SELECT * from Table2
```

Comment: I wanted to know is there a way to do the same using left outer join? I tried 
select [SL No],[Name],[Amount] from table1 as a
 left outerjoin on table2 as b 
(select distinct [Payment Mode] from b) 
where a.[Payment Mode] = b.[Payment mode]. 
When I execute it throws an error. Please help me in correcting the code.